# Jquery Remove NextAll not working on Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is my problem,

Couldn't find any working solution in related/similar questions I found on StackOverflow.

I have a select which is filled with ajax data, let's call this the "mainSelect" which has a "selectSomething" class.
On event (change/keyup), if the selected value is not '', then it automatically adds a "subChoice" select under the first one, which also have the "selectSomething" class.

When user chooses something in the 2nd select, then it adds (or not, depends of which value is selected) a new select under the current one (still with a selectSomething class). And so on. Like this :

Here is the html part :

```
<div class='choiceDiv'>
    <select class='selectSomething' id='masterSelect'>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the Js part :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        populateMainSelect();
        //does its job correctly
    });
    $(document).on('change keyup','.selectSomething',function(){
        if($(this).val()!=''){
            //Need here to remove all sub-choices selects
            //NEXT LINE NOT WORKING !
            $(this).parent().nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
            //And add or not a new one
            if(/*NeedToAddASubSelectCheck*/){
                //PopulateMySelect is a function that fills a jquery element. Like this  : 
                // function PopulateMySelect(elementToFill,dataToEnter,callback);
                PopulateMySelect($('<select>',{
                    class:'selectSomething'
                }).appendTo('#choiceDiv')),data,function(){
                    console.log('select is created, filled and added on page');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Maybe the "logic" of this is somehow not optimal, you may have advices to give me about that,

but the main point to me now is that the line

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
```

is not working... Any idea?

Thanks for reading/help

**Edit :**

If I output this in console :

```
console.log($(this).nextAll('.selectSomething'));
```

I get an object [] which has a length of 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$(this).nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
```

instead of

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
```

as you will need to get the closest parent then find any select inside it and remove it.

**Explanation:**

*Your code*

```
$(this)         // this here is the selectSomething dropdown
    .parent()   // this is the choiceDiv parent div element
    .nextAll('.selectSomething')    // there nothing next to choiceDiv
    .remove();  // that's why this remove does not works here
```

Comment: I'll try, BUT I need to remove all "following" .selectSomething selects, and NOT current (the one which fired the event)

Comment: I may arrive to something like  5 following selects with selected value, and I change value of the 3rd one. So at that moment, selects 4 and 5 must disappear and event fired on 3rd select change makes appear (or not) a 4th select... Idk if i explain it clearly or not...

Comment: @Julo0sS: you can simply do `$(this).nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();` then. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

For next you dont need call parent() because in this case you will get next elements after **parent**.

Try just:

```
$(this).nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.selectSomething').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

after

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.selectSomething').remove();
```

because after removing elements from select box dynamically and adding options to it dynamically, it needs to be refreshed